# Python: how to loop through folders and files and index them in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a bunch of folders, each containing a set and equal number of files. I want to use python to loop through each folder and do some analysis to each file. I want to store the results of the analysis within a numpy array.

For example, suppose we have 3 folders, each containing 5 files. I want the analysis results to be stored within an array `results=np.zeros((3,5))`

Here's a code snippet close to what I want, but not correct.

```
results=np.zeros((3,5))
dircount=0
filecount=0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOTFOLDER):
  for dir in root:
    for file in dirs:
      result[dircount,filecount]=#do some analysis with file
      filecount=filecount+1
    dircount=dircount+1
    filecount=0
print result
```

I must confess, I do not fully understand how os.walk works, but it seems good for jobs involving a loop through files and folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.walk()` does the most part of what you're trying to do manually:

```
results=np.zeros((3,5))
dircount=0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOTFOLDER):
    filecount = 0
    for f in files:
        #  absolute filename is os.path.join(root, f)
        result[dircount,filecount] = #do some analysis with file
        filecount += 1
    dircount += 1       
print result
```

The main loop will walk down all folders in `dirs` recursively, and thus you get all files in that folder tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.walk` here

```
results=np.zeros((3,5))
dircount=0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ROOTFOLDER):
    filecount = 0
    for f in files:
        #  absolute path is os.path.join(root,f)
        result[dircount,filecount]
        filecount += 1
    dircount += 1
```

print result

If you need complete files_list in the folder reccursively

```
files_list = [os.path.join(folder,i) for folder, subdirs, files in os.walk(ROOTFOLDER) for i in files]
```